# 24bit png opacity in MSIE7 / MSIE8 with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Is there a way to make it work? It works well in other browsers but in MSIE 8 it acts as if  the png has a solid background. Works fine with png images that have a solid background but often I need semitransparent pngs and changing the opacity of those with jQuery doesn't work properly.

Also if it's not possible or too complicated how would I hide such code from MSIE browsers? jQuery documentation says not to use jQuery.browser but to use jQuery.support but how do I test for this feature of properly handling 24 bit pngs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem which requires you to code a workaround. How to do it is here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294714

Excerpt:

If you browse to a Web page that contains an image that has a transparent background in Portable Network Graphics (PNG) format, the image background may appear to be gray rather than transparent.

MORE INFORMATION

Web developers who work with PNG files can use the AlphaImageLoader filter...